# Magento SE Swag #2

Tags: discussion, community, event

Before you read this, I want you to know that I have StackExchange's blessing to announce this, so this is not spam.

## The prize:

A [magento SE t-shirt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x048B.jpg) size L courtesy of StackExchange:

## Where & When:

[Meet Magento Romania 2016](http://ro.meet-magento.com/)  Cluj, Romania October 28th - 29th 2016

## How can you get it.

- you have to personally attend MeetMagento Romania 2016
- you have to have an account on magento.stackexchange.com
- you have to have at least 200 reputation points until October 27th 2016 23:59.

  - you have 2 months to get it if you don't already have it.
  - association bonus does not count (so 300 rep if you have the association bonus).
- you must NOT be among the users that already received a t-shirt.
- you must NOT cheat. I have moderator friends that can check for multiple accounts or voting fraud.
- once you reach the reputation threshold you have to tweet (until October 27th 2016 23:59):

  > "I want the t-shirt! #mse-mm16ro [link to your profile page here]".

<sub>The conditions above can be changed over time, but not drastically.</sub>

Oh! and look for me there if you want stickers

[image: stickers]

Comment: Yet another good reason to attend Meet Magento Romania and becoming/being active on magento.stackexchange.com :)

Comment: Every condition is met for me except first one , so you can book Plane tickets for me.  :-) along with t-shirt, the much happier thing is we will get chance to meet you....

Comment: @BabyinMagento. I forgot to mention something. How you get there it's your problem. :)

Comment: oh no, i thought you guys will book ticket for us :-)

Comment: @Marius can you deliver the t-shirt? i will pay delivery charges  :D

Comment: @QaisarSatti as Marius don't like shipping charges , so he wrote module to [hide shipping method](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/53355/remove-shipping-steps-in-onepage-checkout) , he will deliver the shirt for you for free :-)

Comment: @QaisarSatti.read the first condition...you have to be there.

Comment: @Marius to fulfill first condition   **invitation on behalf of Romanian citizens**  needed.

Comment: @Marius in this opportunity, it's really hard to get a t-shirt for me. At this time, I'm one of the first 72 users, but I don't have any t-shirt. I hope I will get one on others.:)

Comment: @KhoaTruongDinh don't worry,  i will downvote on all your questions & answers, so that your name may display out of those list, i am requesting all commuity members to downvote your posts :-)

Comment: @BabyinMagento :) we need some t-shirts.

Comment: @KhoaTruongDinh sure you will get, i already started downvoting your posts,   my goal is to help you to get t-shirts :-)

Comment: I don't have twitter, now what?

Comment: @rene. If only there was a way to get a twitter account....but since there is not, I guess you are out of the competition.

Comment: There should be some other condition then meet romania b'coz many acrtive users won't come there , but they actively participate in community so they deserve this t-shirt

Comment: @murtuza I totally agree with you. But this one is for Meet magento Romania, because I live in Romania, because I'm attending the conference and can hand out the t-shirt personally, because of many reasons. This is not organized by StackeExchange. I did it. I just asked them for their blessing and a free t-shirt.

Comment: The rule states that you have to be there. The idea of this is to encourage people to participate to that event (in which I have no administrative involvement and get no money out of it, just to be clear) and to be active on magento SE if they are not. I will not send you the t-shirt.

Comment: I guess you have to create a new Magento website to sell t-shirts now Marius :p

Comment: @Marius, the dash breaks the hashtag on Twitter but still searchable, btw. I just tweeted :)